# Correct way of using session data in other layers while logging

Tags: java, logging, design-patterns, web

I want to write some info logs that include executor info. Let's say I have this SaveUser function:

```
public class UserDAO {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void SaveUser(User user, LoggerInfo info) {
        logger.info("Executor {} trying to save user {}...", "Executor name comes here", user.name);

        this.saveToFirstDB(user);
        this.saveToSecondDB(user);

        logger.info("Executor {} succesfully saved user {}.", "Executor name comes here", user.name);
    }

    private void SaveToFirstDB(User user) {
        logger.info("Executor {}, enter SaveToFirstDB.", "Executor name comes here", user.name);

        // save user to first db..

        logger.info("Executor {}, exit SaveToFirstDB.", "Executor name comes here", user.name);
    }

    private void SaveToSecondDB(User user) {
        logger.info("Executor {}, enter SaveToSecondDB.", "Executor name comes here", user.name);
        I
        // save user to second db..

        logger.info("Executor {}, exit SaveToSecondDB.", "Executor name comes here", user.name);        
    }
}
```

And I want to call it at the Controller layer:

```
public class UserController{

    // for example - using Java Spark request and response context
    public void SaveUser(Request req, Response res) {
        User userToSave = new User(.....); // creating user object from request params

        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        userDAO.SaveUser(userToSave);

        // I want to use this executor name:
        System.out.println(req.attribute("executor"));
    }
}
```

Of course I can inject the executor name, but I do not think I should do that (this is just a simple example, I want to inject more details like date, role, etc..).

I do not want to inject the details, and I do not want the DAL (for example) to know about the context object of the Controller layer (Play, Spark..).
So what is the correct way to write informative logs at backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Log4j Mapped Diagnostic Context. In this approach, you can write a request interceptor or servlet filter to set additional properties in Log4j MDC.
Your servlet filter look like below-

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            /*
             * This code puts the value "userName" to the Mapped Diagnostic
             * context. Since MDc is a static class, we can directly access it
             * with out creating a new object from it. Here, instead of hard
             * coding the user name, the value can be retrieved from a HTTP
             * Request object.
             */
            MDC.put("userName", req.attribute("executor"));
            MDC.put("date", System.currentTimeMilis());
            MDC.put("role", getRole()); 
            //Any other properties you want to set
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        } finally {
            MDC.remove("userName");
        }
    }
```

Then you can write cutomize log4j pattern for your UserDao class.

```
[%d{ISO8601}] %X{userName} %X{role} %p %c - %m%n
```

Above syntax is just for reference.

Comment: this is exactly how we do it at my job